# angularjs force query to server instead loading from cache

Tags: angularjs, caching

I have a controller that start like following:

```
  function CartCtrl($scope, Cart, $modal, Product) {
  $scope.doWobble = null;
  $scope.isCartUpdated = false;
  $scope.items = Cart.query();
  updateTotal();
  $scope.alerts = [
    { visible: false},
    { msg: 'it's empty', visible: false}
  ];

  $scope.items.$promise.then(function () {
    updateTotal();
  });
  ....
```

So, in chrome, when I hit the Back button, it load items from cache.
How can I force it to never use cache and make a query to server?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cache control header server side.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
```

Comment: Then only set it for that page.

Comment: How, where do I set http headers in angular for responses to a route?